# Vuejs 3 at click change data in the components

Tags: vue.js

I create a Components like that:

**Card Component:**

```
<template>  
   <div> 
      <svg v-if="like.find(e=>e==product.p_id)" @click='likes(product.p_id)' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6 text-gray-400 cursor-pointer" fill='#c30' viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke='#c30'>
           <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4.318 6.318a4.5 4.5 0 000 6.364L12 20.364l7.682-7.682a4.5 4.5 0 00-6.364-6.364L12 7.636l-1.318-1.318a4.5 4.5 0 00-6.364 0z" />
      </svg>
      <svg v-else @click='likes(product.p_id)' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6 text-gray-400 cursor-pointer" fill='none' viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke='currentColor'>
            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4.318 6.318a4.5 4.5 0 000 6.364L12 20.364l7.682-7.682a4.5 4.5 0 00-6.364-6.364L12 7.636l-1.318-1.318a4.5 4.5 0 00-6.364 0z" />
      </svg>
   </div>
</template>
```

```
    data() {
        return {
            like: [],
        }
    },
    methods:{
        likes(id){
            let keys = Object.keys(localStorage);
            for(let key of keys) {
                this.like.push(localStorage.getItem(key));
            }
            if(!this.like.includes(id.toString())){
                this.like.push(id);
                localStorage['likes' + id] = id
            }else{
                localStorage.removeItem('likes' + id)
                this.like.splice(this.like.indexOf(id))
            }
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        let keys = Object.keys(localStorage);
            for(let key of keys) {
                this.like.push(localStorage.getItem(key));
            }
    },
```

and in the **Home Component** I used **Card Component** twice,
the problem is at the **Click event** in **Card component** when I click it's changing only in one component and after reload the page its applied the changes.

**Home Component:**

```
<card :product="ProdLastest" />
<card :product="Hotest" />
```

Comment: Is this data and methods parts of Home or Card component? Also consider making a [mcve] like codesandbox

Comment: It's part of card component

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by use **Vuex**

I just store the data value (**like**) and then append it in Card component from **store state**

Comment: For small use case you can lift the state to home component and use props

Comment: I thought about that, I will try it with another think, thank you so much